# Query not executing in Elasticsearch input plugin for Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I'm new to the stack, and am trying to execute simple queries in logstash via the elasticsearch input plugin. I have worked through some initial errors and now have only a couple of notable warnings, but am not getting any output from the query.

I've verified that the query works properly in elasticsearch itself and that the output functions properly using by using a generator. Here is the config, with some private info swapped out.

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        id => "es_input_plugin"
        user => myuser
        password => mypassword
        hosts => myhost
        ca_file => "C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\rootca3.crt"
        ssl => true
        index => "log-com-ms-ldap--*"
        query => '{ 
                    "query": {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-1d/d"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "size": 1
                }'
        docinfo => true
        docinfo_target => "[@metadata][doc]"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    
    email { 
        to => myemail
        from => mysystem
        subject => 'Success'
        body => 'Success'
        address => myaddress
        via => 'smtp'
    }
}
```

And here is the output I get when running the file.

```
C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\bin>logstash.bat -f C:\Users\ElamR\Documents\elasticinput.conf
"Using bundled JDK: C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\jdk\bin\java.exe"
Sending Logstash logs to C:/devsetup/logstash-8.6.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2023-02-23T13:01:56,964][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\config\log4j2.properties
[2023-02-23T13:01:56,973][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] The use of JAVA_HOME has been deprecated. Logstash 8.0 and later ignores JAVA_HOME and uses the bundled JDK. Running Logstash with the bundled JDK is recommended. The bundled JDK has been verified to work with each specific version of Logstash, and generally provides best performance and reliability. If you have compelling reasons for using your own JDK (organizational-specific compliance requirements, for example), you can configure LS_JAVA_HOME to use that version instead.
[2023-02-23T13:01:56,975][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.6.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.3.8.0 (2.6.8) 2022-09-13 98d69c9461 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.5+8 on 17.0.5+8 +indy +jit [x86_64-mswin32]"}
[2023-02-23T13:01:56,980][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
[2023-02-23T13:01:57,019][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2023-02-23T13:01:58,272][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[2023-02-23T13:01:58,700][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 180 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 127 keys and 444 values
[2023-02-23T13:02:01,422][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline `main` is configured with `pipeline.ecs_compatibility: v8` setting. All plugins in this pipeline will default to `ecs_compatibility => v8` unless explicitly configured otherwise.
[2023-02-23T13:02:02,095][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["C:/Users/ElamR/Documents/elasticinput.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6f11e638@C:/devsetup/logstash-8.6.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:131 run>"}
[2023-02-23T13:02:02,797][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.7}
[2023-02-23T13:02:04,827][INFO ][logstash.inputs.elasticsearch][main] ECS compatibility is enabled but `target` option was not specified. This may cause fields to be set at the top-level of the event where they are likely to clash with the Elastic Common Schema. It is recommended to set the `target` option to avoid potential schema conflicts (if your data is ECS compliant or non-conflicting, feel free to ignore this message)
[2023-02-23T13:02:04,831][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2023-02-23T13:02:04,849][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2023-02-23T13:02:05,108][WARN ][logstash.inputs.elasticsearch][main][es_input_plugin] Ignoring clear_scroll exception {:message=>"[404] {\"succeeded\":true,\"num_freed\":0}", :exception=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound}
[2023-02-23T13:02:05,215][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2023-02-23T13:02:05,356][INFO ][logstash.pipelinesregistry] Removed pipeline from registry successfully {:pipeline_id=>:main}
[2023-02-23T13:02:05,362][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

My thoughts have been centered around the final warning, regarding clear_scroll exception, but I have yet to find any related references.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the reported exception in that warn log is `{:message=>"[404] {\"succeeded\":true,\"num_freed\":0}", :exception=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotFound}` , which seems to indicate that elasticsearch (or the index) wasn't found. Could you test that elasticsearch is reachable from logstash, and that the index is correct?

Comment: @glenacota Thanks, I didn't even think about that as it was the node used in an example sent to me by a senior engineer. I think it may have either been down or also possible that I don't have read access.

Answer (score 1):

#### Logstash Pipeline for Elasticsearch to Email

The principal modifications consist of:

- Ensuring that the SSL certificate is checked by specifying the ssl certificate verification option.
- Giving users the opportunity to provide the root certificate for SSL verification with the ssl certificate authorities setting
- A list of hosts is indicated by enclosing the hosts option in an array.
- To guarantee that the email addresses are handled as strings, you should enclose them in quotes.

Here is the updated pipeline

```bash
input {
    elasticsearch {
        id => "es_input_plugin"
        user => "myuser"
        password => "mypassword"
        hosts => ["myhost"]
        ssl_certificate_verification => true
        ssl_certificate_authorities => ["C:\devsetup\logstash-8.6.0\rootca3.crt"]
        ssl => true
        index => "log-com-ms-ldap-*"
        query => '{ 
                    "query": {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "now-1d/d"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "size": 1
                }'
        docinfo => true
        docinfo_target => "[@metadata][doc]"
    }
}

output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    
    email { 
        to => "myemail"
        from => "mysystem"
        subject => 'Success'
        body => 'Success'
        address => "myaddress"
        via => 'smtp'
    }
}
```